# Unable to update OneNote page content

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I send a PATCH request to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onenote/pages/1-3e7c1460680d4fe28501792ccda64915!119-304d54d6-d499-49f0-b231-cb3a9248e4e9/content

with body

```
[
  {
    "action": "replace",
    "target": "p:{3e7c1460-680d-4fe2-8501-792ccda64915}{197}",
    "content": "<p data-tag=\"to-do:completed\" style=\"margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt\">Sdasdsad</p>"
  }
]
```

And I get response 500 with body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "19999",
        "message": "Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "574a3b34-c354-4603-a73e-981984a56758",
            "date": "2018-09-24T08:23:02"
        }
    }
}
```

The error is persistent. Does anybody knows where I can get help?

Comment: Are you trying the command in Graph Explorer? I've just entered the exact patch command via Graph Explorer and it seemed to work.

Comment: @codeye I tried a munite ago and it still fails: https://i.imgur.com/etelxWZ.png
`"request-id": "963e9854-f840-4ce5-beb1-7fb81b95ba40"`

Comment: I have also checked that I use correct id https://i.imgur.com/4al29GH.png

Just in case - how the page looks: https://i.imgur.com/1vaV33D.png

Comment: Can you show the output of a get call on that page?

Comment: @codeye you can find it here https://gist.github.com/zaverden/2d51a11e6e499591d5e965f5ff66d3fe

Comment: If I create a similar page in graph explorer and then patch the paragraph exactly as you do I do not get an error. The html code changes however and the <ul> and <li> tags are lost. I think we might have to wait for microsoft to check your request-id

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/home/chat?ContactUsExperienceEntryPointAssetId=S.HP.onenote will be more suitable than answers